# Android ActionBar tab style for Honeycomb

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

I am using the HoneycombGallery sample app in the SDK and attempting to change the style of the ActionBar tabs (i.e., "Balloons", "Bikes", "Androids", "Pastries").  Using the "light" theme, the tabs have a blue underline.  I simply want to make this red to match the style of an application I'm working on.

I've tried researching styles in the SDK documentation (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) and other sources on the web, but I'm not quite certain that I understand what property/attribute controls this particular style of the tabs.

If anyone has a resource or code example that might demonstrate a complete custom styling of the ActionBar, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'll want to be familiar with applying a custom theme to an activity. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

The theme attributes `android:actionBarTabStyle`, `android:actionBarTabBarStyle`, and `android:actionBarTabTextStyle` control the appearance of action bar tabs. The default styling uses `android:background` within the tab bar style for the thin line under unselected items, and a state list drawable as the `android:background` for the tabs themselves to handle focused/selected/pressed states. The background assets themselves are 9-patches that provide the underline in most cases but a more comprehensive highlight for pressed/focused states.

Comment: Thank you - that helped a lot.  Although I found that the statelist xml file ended up working with android:actionBarTabStyle instead of android:actionBarTabBarStyle.  The resource links you included were a big help though - I have the patch-9 graphics, statelist xml and an overall styles file created to control the layout of the action bar tabs.