# Style Inheritance with ActionBar Tab troubles

Tags: android

Many of my questions about "styling" actionbar tabs were answered by adamp in this [thread on tab style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353465/android-actionbar-tab-style-for-honeycomb), but I am still struggling with my arriving at the desired presentation.

Specifically, I am attempting to do what adamp suggested in the following fragment from my styles.xml file, but, I cannot get the inherited (Widget.holo.actionbar) feature of a light blue line to appear under the selected tab nor is there any indication of selection:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/customActionBarTabTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/customActionBarTabStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/customActionBarTabBarStyle</item>
</style>    

<style name="customActionBarTabTextStyle" parent="@style/CustomActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">#2966c2</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
</style>

<style name="customActionBarTabStyle" parent="@style/CustomActionBar">
    <!-- <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_bg</item> -->
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">20dp</item>
</style>    

<style name="customActionBarTabBarStyle" parent="@style/CustomActionBar">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">240dp</item>
</style>
```

Can someone explain why the thin blue line selection behavior of the Honeycomb Gallery Sample App does not work for me?

New insight since this was written: the problem here, I think, is that the style I have created to overide ActionBarTabStyle is entirely bogus:

```
<style name="customActionBarTabStyle" parent="@style/CustomActionBar">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">20dp</item>
</style>
```

I need to specify the *correct* parent of this style per "Theme.holo"....how can one find where the default style is so it can be specified as a parent?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To specify the correct parents for actionbar style in API 11, Check doc here:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html