# Android Tab underline color not changing

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock

So I've basically looked into every resource I saw online on how to change the blue underline in the tabs, but all of the advice has not worked in my case.

I tried actionbarsherlock, appcombat, holo from [Action Bar Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) but all the coloring did was color the top action bar, not the tab underline. And yes the files did compile and did not have any errors, but for some reason, it seemed like the underline would never be changed even through the generator.

I am confused on how to change the default blue underline on the tabs, and I would SO EXTREMELY appreciate it if there was a working custom style xml that you would share.

After going to [Changing ActionBar tabs underline color programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139259/changing-actionbar-tabs-underline-color-progrmatically/16140075#16140075) result is still same :/

Screen shot after trying from other page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOUbu.png

Anyone able to help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been struggling with this for days, but finally found the solution. I'm using AppCompat. You can set `colorAccent` in your theme and that will change the highlight color on your ActionBar. Like so:

```
<item name="colorAccent">@color/highlightcolor</item>
```

Here it is in context:

```
<style name="LightTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/darkgrey</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/highlightcolor</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a custom theme for that, and then check the states to change the colour of the line. See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16140075) answer helps you

Comment: Hello, I tried what the helpers posted in the other page, but the underline colors seem to not work :/

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/pTxSv.png This is the screenshot of my phone when I follow through action bar generator.

As you can see, there's a red line above, but the blue underline still stays the same for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still pursuing this, but can you show what you did with Action Bar Generator?  What Style entries did you add (in XML) and which drawables did you add?

I just went through the same process and it worked well with Action Bar Generator; just required a few lines added to the styles.xml, a new xml file in drawables folder, and then about 5 new image drawables into each of the resolution size folders (drawable-hdpi, etc).